# What is background scan in Win32 WiFi native API?

Tags: winapi, wifi

What does it mean when we enable/disable background scan in Win32 WiFi Native API?
What is WiFi 'background scan'?

See the `wlan_intf_opcode_background_scan_enabled` opcode in the
[`WlanSetInterface()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlansetinterface) function:

> Enables or disables background scan for the indicated interface.

Comment: It means "background scan" exactly.

Comment: The current default behavior for background scan is that *the Wireless LAN Service only asks the wireless interface driver to scan for wireless networks every 60 seconds, and in some cases (when already connected to wireless network) the Wireless LAN Service does not ask for scans at all.*